# How to update existing xml element with new given element using python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have input XML as country.xml:-

```
<root>
<set>
    <name>Countries</name>
    <elements>
    <name>US</name>
    <city>
        <val>New York</val>
        <val>Las Vegas</val>
    </city>
    </elements>
    <elements>
    <name>UK</name>
    <city>
        <val>London</val>
    </city>
    </elements>
</set>
</root>
```

I am parsing xml and taking it into a list and i have a dictionary based on which I am comparing and adding xml elements.

```
diction: dict = {'US':['New York', 'Chicago'], 'UK':['OXFORD', 'London']}
source = etree.getroot()
for key,value in diction.items()
    countrylist = source.xpath('./elements/name[text()=\'{}\']/..'.format(key))
    if len(countrylist) == 0:
        # creating new string and element
        # appending element to original tree
    elif len(countrylist) == 1:   ###This is problematic case what to expect here to update key,value from dictionary only and replace the tag already present in xml
        key = countrylist[0]
    else:
        countinue

    # writebacktoxml(source,"country.xml")
```

Output I am getting is original input condition as it is in output for specific condition. 
Expected output is below:-

```
<root>
<set>
    <name>Countries</name>
    <elements>
    <name>US</name>
    <city>
        <val>New York</val>
        <val>Chicago</val>
    </city>
    </elements>
    <elements>
    <name>UK</name>
    <city>
        <val>OXFORD</val>
        <val>London</val>
    </city>
    </elements>
</set>
</root>
```

Comment: `key = countrylist[0]` does not update your xml. It only creates a new reference/variable key pointing to countrylist[0]

Comment: @stovfl- how to go about it...can you please suggest it will be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment**: What if `diction:{'AUSTRALIA': ['MELBOURNE']}` ? And I want to keep both the things from dictionary as well as from input xml into output xml?

- Add a condition around `.clear`

  ```
  if name.text in ['AUSTRALIA']:
      # Keep the values
      pass
  else:
      table_category.clear()
  ```

---

> **Question**: How to update existing xml element with new given `<val>...</val>`?

Documentation: [The lxml.etree Tutorial - The E-factory](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-e-factory)
[Python Documentation -The ElementTree XML API - Modifying an XML File](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file)

---

- Example using `lxml`

  ```
  from lxml import etree
  from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
  ```
- Data `dict`

  ```
  diction = {'US': ['New York', 'Chicago'], 'UK': ['OXFORD', 'London']}
  ```
- Instantiate a `ElementMaker` object and a new `<val>...</val>` object.

  ```
  E = ElementMaker()
  VAL = E.val
  ```
- Parse the source `xml`

  ```
  tree = etree.parse(io.StringIO(xmlf))
  root = tree.getroot()
  ```
- Parse all `set/elements`

  ```
  for element in root.findall('set/elements'):
  ```
- Get the `name` of this `element`

  ```
      name = element.find('name')
  ```
- Get the `table_category` of this `element` and `.clear` it

  ```
      table_category = element.find('table_category')
      table_category.clear()
  ```
- Loop **all** items from the `list` in `diction` defined for `[name.text]`.

  ```
      for val in diction[name.text]:
  ```
- Append a **new** `<val>val</val>` to `table_category`

  ```
          table_category.append(VAL(val))
  ```

> **Output**: `print('{}'.format(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode()))`
>
> ```
> <configroot version="8.0">
> <set>
>     <name>Countries</name>
>     <elements>
>     <name>US</name>
>     <table_category><val>New York</val><val>Chicago</val></table_category></elements>
>     <elements>
>     <name>UK</name>
>     <table_category><val>OXFORD</val><val>London</val></table_category></elements>
> </set>
> </configroot>
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: Thanks it's working  now any other alternative for builder or is it inbuilt under lxml?

Comment: @Pyjava: *" any other alternative for builder or is it inbuilt under lxml"*: Can't answer this for sure, added the Documentation link to my answer.

Comment: What if diction:{'AUSTRALIA': ['MELBOURNE']} ? And I want to keep both the things from dictionary as well as from input xml into output xml? There is a test case failure in that case.

Comment: Similar thing in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124953/how-to-update-existing-xml-element-values-and-attributes .......just that it does not has table_category then how would i update the stringval?